# Is the Korean on this van referring to a church?

Tags: translation, meaning, written

Is the Korean written on the side of this van in an episode of *The Office* referring to some sort of Church? Or, what is it saying?[image]
<sup><sub><sub>credit: Office</sub></sub></sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly, we already have this question on the SE network:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-written-on-the-mini-bus

They've translated it as "Hallelujah Church of Scranton", although the word-for-word translation is "Scranton Hallelujah Church".

Scranton = 스크랜턴 
Hallelujah=  할렐루야 
Church = 교회 (only partially visible in the picture)

The Korean alphabet is phonetic, and the first two words are just [transliterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) of the English (or Hebrew, in the second case). '교회' is the normal Korean word for church.

Comment: My searches are not to thorough, apparently. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel easier to search once you know what it says though :)